# C# Dictionary Loop Through Only Certain Datasets

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, foreach

Say I have a Dictionary `wipProfile` which is defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, int> wipProfile = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "L1", 10 }, { "L2", 12 }, { "L3", 23 }, { "L4", 9 } };
```

I wonder how can I only loop through those with value >= 10?

I know I can do something like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> lot in wipProfile)
{
        if (lot.Value >= 10)
        {
            //Do something here.
        }
}
```

But is there a way to specify filtering criteria before entering the loop, so that I don't need to iterate through the entire dictionary, say something like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> lot in wipProfile where lot.Value >= 10){
    //...
}
```

Comment: So, what do you believe would be the difference between the `foreach` and your idea of `so that I don't need to iterate through the entire dictionary`?

Comment: @RandRandom More simplified code mainly. And I can only deal with those that I truly care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using `System.Linq`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> lot in wipProfile.Where(kv => kv.Value >= 10))
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for somethign like this:

```
 wipProfile.Where((key, value) => value > 10).ToList();
```

That will give you the list filtered with online the items that have a value greater than 10. Then you can do a ForEach in Linq style or with the reserved word as you showed!

EDIT:

as Steward mention the right way to do it is like this:

```
 wipProfile.Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value > 10).ToList();
```

Comment: OP wants values greater than 10, your filtering based on index greater than 10.

Comment: I think you are commenting on the wrong answer dude. My solution is filtering using the values of the dictionary. Aotn solution is using the index. Please remove the minus if you were the one who did it, because this works.

Comment: Your using the overload of `Where` that has a `KeyValuePair` and an index, `value` in your code is the index of the element not the value of the `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: You are right Steward. Im sorry. Will edit it below just in case and give you credit.